# VimGolf error with Fugitive

Tags: vim

Trying to learn vim while playing VimGolf. This game is awesome but whenever I try to play it, I get that error in vim: `E117: Unknown function: fugitive#statusline.`

I cannot figure why because I have the fugitive plugin installed in the ~/.vim/bundle and am using Pathogen. By the way Pathogen is properly configured because other plugins in the bundle directory are actually working.

The game is playable despite of that problem but it adds characters at the beginning of the answer I provide. This is pretty bad considering that the shortest answer, the better.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: someone downvoted without an explanation. How sad.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably getting called because you have something like `set statusline = ... %{fugitive#statusline()}...` in your `.vimrc`. Assuming this is the case, you should check two things:

1. Is the syntax correct? The quoted form I have included is straight from my `.vimrc`, which works.
2. Do you even want this? If the syntax is correct and it's still giving you errors (maybe for some
   weird pathogen reason?), but you just don't care so much about knowing your git branch in your
   status line, you might as well just remove the whole `%{}` block from the line and make your life
   simpler.